# What wire gauge for use for JST-XH connectors with and without insulation?

Tags: connector, wire, gauge, awg, small-gauge-wire

I bought a variety kit of JST-XH connectors on ebay:

[image]

The auction says:

> Wire Range: AWG 32-24
>
> Insulation O.D.: 1.00mm (Max)

But Wikipedia says that this connector supports AWG 30-22 and does not mention insulation.

Is the auction listed without insulation and the Wikipedia article without?

Comment: It's easy enough to look up the manufacturer's own data on this.

Comment: Read the data sheet... Oh you bought on eBay.... good luck.

Comment: The same connector housing usually can accept several kinds of contacts, for different wire sizes and insulation thickness. You got what you got, and Wikipedia is not a replacement for manufacturer's specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWG has nothing to do with insulation. It is a *wire gauge*, after all. Read [JST XH datasheet](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eXH.pdf) and you'll find compatible wire AWG.

XH housing supports 3 sizes: for 26~22, 28~22 and 30~26. Therefore Wikipedia correctly provides the full range as 30~22. The auction listing is different from all of them so either it is a mistake in text or you've bought some 3rd party product with unknown properties.

Insulation OD is also provided in datasheet. The design of crimp contacts can accept quite wide range of insulation thickness, the limiting factor is usually the size of the opening in the plastic housing. Although the reliability of the crimp will be reduced if you use diameter outside of the specified range.

In my experience these connectors easily accept 22 AWG with thick silicone insulation.

Comment: Thank you for the summary and a link to the datasheet. I can see that I was given a set of "Shape B" contacts which are stated as being for 30-22.